# Scan redis sorted set in order

Tags: redis, node-redis

I'm using `node redis` to connect to redis.

The `zscan` function provided by redis does not return elements in order. I was wondering if there's a `javascript` library that helps me do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `ZRANGE` command to scan the sorted set. You only need to record how many elements you have already scanned.

```
// scan from the element with the smallest score (ascending order)
var index = 0
var count = 10
ZRANGE key index index + count - 1
index += count
ZRANGE key index index + count - 1
// until all elements have been scanned
```

With the `ZREVRANGE` command, you can also scan the sorted set in descending order.